# Cron job every day at 9:27

Tags: cron

I'm having some problem with crontab.
I have this job:

> 27 09 * * * drush @ildeposito.prod status

I want to execute the cron job every day at 9:27.
But it doesn't work.
If I try to execute the command directly in prompt it works.

What's wrong on my crontab?

If I execute "date" from shell I obtain:

> mar  3 set 2013, 12.55.13, CEST

If I put the output of date in a file, with a cron job, I obtain:

> Tue Sep  3 12:55:01 CEST 2013

Another: this is NOT executed every minute on 13!

```
* 13 * * * date >>/tmp/temp_out_hour
```

This works:

> */15 * * * * drush @site.prod cache-warmer --timeout=6 --hub-pages-file=/home/sergej/websites/sute/site-cache.txt
>   http://www.site.org

The system seems to have problems with hours.

Comment: Can you confirm that crond is running (ps -ef | grep cron)? Is it the system cron or some weird beast? Is this on your own box or a hosts? These (and possibly more) questions will narrow things down.

Comment: It's a VPS. Cron is running, other cron jobs are ok.

Comment: Okay, so how do you add that cron job? With `crontab -e`? Direct editing? In addition, was the `* 13 * * *` job executed _at all?_ You stated not every minute but did you mean it was less than 1/min, or did it never actually execute?

Comment: I use crontab -e. I've other jobs working. I've tried 43 14 * * * but at 14:43 the job not starts..

Comment: sergio, you didn't answer all the questions. Did that job run at all? And a couple of new ones: is the malfunctioning job on the last line of the file and is it terminated with a newline character? Show us a job that _does_ work.

Comment: The job is the last and there is a blank line at the end

Comment: Good. Now back to the earlier question :-) **In addition, was the "* 13 * * *" job executed at all? You stated not every minute but did you mean it was less than 1/min, or did it never actually execute?**

Comment: The file temp_out_hour doesn't exists

Comment: "25 15 * * * date >>/tmp/temp_out_marco" this works on a server of a friend, not on my server -.-

Comment: Right, can you do a hex dump on the crontab file to see if there's any suspect characters in there?

Comment: file is ok.. if I simply replace "25 15 * * *" with "10 * * * *" it works

Comment: Bizarre! It looks like there may be something wrong with your cron. I'd suggest looking into that. Compare it with your friends for a start (such as with md5sum or cksum). Try restarting the cron daemon as well.

Comment: On my server the same configuraiton works.. however thanks

Comment: Ok, "simply" stop and restart cron daemon works -.- :(

Answer (score 3):

First things first, you need to specify what "it doesn't work" actually means. Do you mean you see no output? Get no mail sent to you with the output? Typically, standard output from `cron` jobs will be packaged up in an email and sent to the user running the job. If you want to see what the job is outputting, you can use something like:

```
27 9 * * * drush @ildeposito.prod status >/tmp/temp_out 2>&1
```

which will write standard output an error to that file (you also don't *need* the leading `0` in `09`).

If a command works from a shell prompt and not from `cron`, it's usually a difference in your environment settings. You can test this by replacing your job with a very simple one:

```
27 9 * * * date >>/tmp/temp_out
```

and examining that file after it executes. If the `date` works but `drush` doesn't, your problem lies outside of `cron` itself.

`cron` starts processes with a minimal set of environment variables and you have to ensure you've configured a suitable set. See, for example, [here](http://drush.ws/docs/cron.html):

> We use /usr/bin/env to run drush so that we can set up some necessary environment variables that drush needs to execute. By default, cron will run each command with an empty PATH, which would not work well with drush.
>
> When running drush in a terminal, the number of columns will be automatically deteremined by drush by way of the tput command, which queries the active terminal to determine what the width of the screen is. When running drush from cron, there will not be any terminal set, and the call to tput will produce an error message. Spurrious error messages are undesirable, as cron is often configured to send email whenever any output is produced, so it is important to make an effort to insure that successful runs of cron complete with no output.
>
> In some cases, drush is smart enough to recognize that there is no terminal -- if the terminal value is empty or "dumb", for example. However, there are some "non-terminal" values that drush does not recognize, such as "unknown." If you manually set COLUMNS, then drush will repect your setting and will not attempt to call tput.

Other than that, there are numerous other problems that can plague cron:

- having a command on the final line of the file with no newline at the end sometimes causes troubles.
- having `%` in your command somewhere.
- having had the `cron` daemon start with a different timezone setting.

That last one can sometimes be fixed just by restarting the daemon. Given your comments about the bizarre nature of the non-performance, I'd suggest that as a first step.

Comment: Other drush commands on cron works.
The problem is with our.
10 * * * * drush @ildeposito.prod status  --- works

Comment: But "* 10 * * * drush @ildeposiot.prod status  does not works

Comment: @sergiod, you need to define what "works" and "does not work" actually means. For example, where is the output of drush ib your good cron examples going that you're certain it's working? And I hesitate to ask a simple question, but are you certain the time has passed? That's why you should first check with the date command, to isolate the problem to cron or drush.

Comment: works = cron is executed (I saw it on syslog)
does not work = cron is not execute (not in syslog)

Comment: @sergiod, try it with the date command and see what comes out. syslog is not _always_ reliable.

Comment: here is the output of date: mar  3 set 2013, 12.36.16, CEST

Comment: @serigod, you need to use one of the cron specs that you say isn't working, and test that with date. The 12.36.16 doesn't seem to match any of the failing ones you've listed. My advice is to use it with the 9.27 one and wait till tomorrow morning. Then let us know what comes out in the file. That should prove that it's running.